# Flutter Slider Widget is not animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wrote the code for slider widget in which you can get the height by sliding.
But the problem is, that when you print the height in console, it's correct.
But the slider is neither moving, nor is the height value changing during runtime.
I have even build an APK, but the problem still persists in a physical device.

```
SliderTheme(
                data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                  inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                  activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                  thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                  overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
                  thumbShape:
                  RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
                  overlayShape:
                  RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
                ),
                child: Slider(
                  value: height.toDouble(),
                  min: 120.0,
                  max: 220.0,
                  onChanged: (double newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      height = newValue.round();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Even setState method is used.
int height is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem
I was initializing the height value in
 `@override Widget build(BuildContext context)` method.
Instead, height value should be initialised in
 `_InputPageState(stateful widget class)` method outside of
 `@override Widget build(BuildContext context)` method